# Guardar datos en un array con metodo post en php

Tags: php

> Buenas tardes, soy nuevo con este lenguaje y no se mucho todavía,
>   estoy intentando que muestre el nombre y la fecha de publicacion del disco que le introduzco el problema que como hago para mostrar los valores del array?,  mi formulario es este:

```
             <?php
            //creo el formulario
            echo '<section >';
            echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '" method="POST">';
            echo '<h1>Insertar Discos</h1>';

            echo '<label>Nombre Discos: </label>';
            echo '<input type="text" name="nombre_disco" value="nombre_disco"></input>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</br>';

            echo '<label>Fecha de Publicación: </label>';
            echo '<input type="date" name="fecha_publicacion" value="fecha_publicacion"></input>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</br>';
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<input type="submit" name= "discos" value="Insertar Disco"/>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</form>';
```

> Y Este es mi codigo hago mi insertar los datos:

```
     //comprobamos que se ha enviado algo
        if($_POST){
            //comprobamos los errores
            $errores=[];
            if(!isset($_POST['nombre_disco'])){
                $errores="Introduce un nombre del disco correcto";
                //si no hay errores continuamos introduciendo los nombres de los campos
            }else{
                //declaramos las variables de los campos
                $nombre_disco=$_POST['nombre_disco'];
                $fecha_publicacion=$_POST['fecha_publicacion'];
                //y los almacenamos en un array
                $discos=array("Nombre_disco" =>$nombre_disco,"fecha_publicacion"=>$fecha_publicacion);

                foreach ($discos as $key => $value) {
                    echo 'El nombre del disco '.$key.' esta publicado el día '.$fecha_publicacion.'</br>';
                }
            }
        }else{

        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Te falta negar el `isset` asi: `if(!isset($_POST['nombre_disco'])){`

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha venido de lujo, negando el isset se refiere es que si no he introducido el nombre que lo introduzca no?

Comment: Correcto, tenias las condiciones al revez.

Comment: Ahora como hago para que me muestre los values de lo que esta almacenado en el array